# Windows Phone Mango choosers

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a problem with using the various choosers.
When I launch one of them at the moment it should return to my application all I get is a "resuming" screen with the progressbar animated indefinetely. Pressing back or the start button does nothing and after a while it gets to the home screen. And the launch of the app again is sluggish.

[choosers problematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThTFq.png)

This happens on the emulator as well as on the mobile itself.

An example of my class that uses a chooser that fails to come back is:

```
public partial class Add : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        GameInviteTask gameInviteTask;

        public Add()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            gameInviteTask = new GameInviteTask();
            gameInviteTask.Completed += new EventHandler<TaskEventArgs>(gameInviteTask_Completed);
        }

        private void TextBox_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                gameInviteTask.SessionId = "<my session id>";
                gameInviteTask.Show();
            }
            catch (System.InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred when choosing an email contact.");
            }
        }

        void gameInviteTask_Completed(object sender, TaskEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.TaskResult)
            {
                //Game logic for when the invite was sent successfully
                case TaskResult.OK:
                    MessageBox.Show("Game invitation sent.");
                    break;

                //Game logic for when the invite is cancelled by the user
                case TaskResult.Cancel:
                    MessageBox.Show("Game invitation cancelled.");
                    break;

                // Game logic for when the invite could not be sent
                case TaskResult.None:
                    MessageBox.Show("Game invitation could not be sent.");
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
```

This happens with all choosers.
I uses the main page to navigate to this one using the navigation service.

What could be the problem?!

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem...

unfortunately the only thing I did not try when trying everything was to remove IsReadOnly from the textbox that runs the Tap event.

So this is a Microsoft bug :/

Windows phone 7.1: **Choosers do not work when you run them from a Tap event of a textbox that has the IsReadOnly True.**

I'll leave it here so it might help others.